# Error in Installing the Cairo R Package

Tags: macos, r, cairo

I am attempting to install the `Cairo` package in the development version of R on Mac OS X 10.7.4, but I'm running into an issue that I cannot resolve.

I have installed Cairo with homebrew (i.e., `brew install cairo`) and received the following message:

> ==> Caveats This formula is keg-only, so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.
>
> Mac OS X already provides this program and installing another version
>   in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> The Cairo provided by Leopard is too old for newer software to link
>   against.
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add its lib
>   & include paths to your build variables:
>
> ```
> LDFLAGS  -L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.2/lib
> CPPFLAGS -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.2/include
> ```

With the above message in mind, I attempted to install the `Cairo` package from R-Forge with the following R command:

> install.packages("Cairo", repos="http://www.rforge.net/", configure.args = c("CAIRO_LIBS=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.2/lib", "CAIRO_CFLAGS=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.2/include/cairo"))

I receive the following error:

> checking cairo.h usability... no
>
> checking cairo.h presence... no
>
> checking for cairo.h... no
>
> configure: error: Cannot find cairo.h!
>
> Please install cairo (http://www.cairographics.org/) and/or set
>
> CAIRO_CFLAGS/LIBS correspondingly. ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’

I repeated the same command without the `repos` argument (by default, I use the FHCRC mirror) with the same result.

At this point, the problem seems obvious: the file `cairo.h` is not present. But then I listed the files in the `include/cairo` directory. Here's the response:

> ls /usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.2/include/cairo
>
> cairo-deprecated.h cairo-ft.h 
>   cairo-ps.h
>   cairo-script-interpreter.h
>   cairo-svg.h
>   cairo-xcb.h
>   cairo-xlib.h
>   cairo-features.h
>   cairo-pdf.h
>   cairo-quartz.h
>   cairo-script.h
>   cairo-version.h
>   cairo-xlib-xrender.h
>   cairo.h

So, I'm pointing the installation of the `Cairo` package to the appropriate place, but the error persists. I have tried variations, such as `CAIRO_CFLAGS=/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.12.2/include`, with no luck.

Thoughts? Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

In case it's necessary, here is my `sessionInfo`:

> R Under development (unstable) (2012-08-08 r60208) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0 (64-bit)
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] BiocInstaller_1.5.12
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] tools_2.16.0

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but on a Unix platform, I would usually associate this behavior with not having the development package for Cairo. I can't speak for Mac on this one, but many *nix packages have a binary package, and a dev package containing all the source and includes. It's possible cairo.h is in there, and not in the include directory where you think it is. The fact that the directory is called "includes" can be deceptive. :-Z

Comment: @RyanRosario - I'm not entirely sure what the issue was, but see my answer below. Basically, we manually installed all of the necessary C libraries from scratch.

Comment: Good! I've noticed that with certain rare packages A, all dependencies either need to be binary or built from source together, which is unfortunate. This makes it a pain when you have another package C that requires a different version of a prerequisite B for package A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker and I just fixed the problem by ignoring all of what I typed above. Rather, we installed Cairo and *all* of its dependencies from source manually, thereby bypassing the usage of `brew` or variants like `port`. This worked like a charm, so I am not entirely sure what was wrong above.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue with cairo config error, and I already installed cairo with homebrew. Try below

```
brew install pkg-config
```

This solved mine problem.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything listed here, I found this blog post about installing the "full R package" using brew: https://luispuerto.net/blog/2018/05/11/installing-r-with-homebrew-with-all-the-capabilities/

What finally worked for me was building R explicitly with cairo (brew's default R tap uses --without-cairo and simply editing the tap did not solve the issue for me).

Works like a charm for me with R 4.0.2, cairo 1.16.0_3 under macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Answer (score 0):

Installing from source in homebrew:

```
 brew install R --build-from-source
```

caused R to be linked to the appropriate cairo library for me.